# Jasmine: callThrough and callFake

Tags: testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have just started investigating in Jasmine, and currently, I am having trouble understanding the call through, return value, and call fake spies.

I read the official documentation, but it doesn't make much sense to me. In addition, I tried to search for an answer on StackOverflow or Google, but couldn't find a sufficient explanation.

Could anyone please explain it in a more dummy-friendly way? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spy on a method, you transform the method to be able to be book kept on when it is called, how many times it was called and with what arguments it was called.

```
class X {
  addNums(x + y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

const x = new X();
const addNumsSpy = spyOn(x, 'addNums');
const result = x.sayHello(1, 2);
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
console.log(result);
```

The result above will be undefined since we installed a spy on `addNums`. You would expect it to be 3 but it won't be because of the spy. In short, a spyOn removes implementation details and it gives you access to if it was called and how it was called.

`callThrough`, `returnValue`, and `callFake` spies come into play when we don't want to lose the implementation details.

callThrough basically says use the implementation details (don't stub undefined).

```
const x = new X();
const addNumsSpy = spyOn(x, 'addNums').and.callThrough();
const result = x.sayHello(1, 2);
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Result will be 3 in the above because we said `callThrough` (actually call the function for us).

returnValue returns the value right away ignoring the implementation details

```
const x = new X();
const addNumsSpy = spyOn(x, 'addNums').and.returnValue(1000);
const result = x.sayHello(1, 2);
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Result will be 1000 in the above because of the `returnValue` (ignore the implementation details and return this value)

callFake allows you to call another function every time the spied function is called.

```
const x = new X();
const addNumsSpy = spyOn(x, 'addNums').and.callFake((num1, num2) => {
  console.log(num1, num2);
  return num1 * num2;
});
const result = x.sayHello(1, 2);
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(addNumsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
console.log(result);
```

The previous result should be 2 because we changed the implementation details of the spied function to multiply instead of add.

Comment: What's the purpose of return value? 
In my understanding, we ignore both the return value and the implementation of the function right?
Why can't we just have a spy on a method and declare another variable equal to the value you want to return?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want a `returnValue` because you want the function being spied on (the spy) to return a value instantaneously. It doesn't have to go through the hoops of if statements and loops, it can straight return a value. For instance, for the addNumsSpy, we want 54.4654, we can just return that value. We don't have to think too hard to find two numbers that add up to that value.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks again